# Display image and filter team members according to id in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to display and team members of selected photographer id. But I am not getting image as well as team. Nothing is showing.

**models.py**

```
class Photographer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    studio_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


class Gallery(models.Model):
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover_photos/',null=True,blank=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I am using foreignkey in Gallery table and in Team table.

**views.py**

```
def visit_photography_site(request,id):
    photographer = Photographer.objects.get(id=id)

    gallery = Gallery.objects.filter(photographer=photographer.user.id)
    team = Team.objects.filter(photographer=photographer.user.id)
    context = {
        'photographer':photographer,
        'gallery':gallery,
        'team':team,
    }
    return render(request,'app/home.html',context)
```

I want to display/filter gallery and team of the photographer according to particular photographer id.

**home.html**

```
<img class="sp-image" src="{{ gallery.cover_photo.url }}" alt="Slider 1"/>
<h1 class="sp-layer slider-text-big" data-position="bottom" data-vertical="25%" data-show-transition="top" data-hide-transition="top" data-show-delay="1500" data-hide-delay="200">
<span class="highlight-texts">{{ photographer.studio_name }}</span>
```

Here I want to display cover photo which is field in Gallery table and there is Foreign Key from Photographer table.
If I click on photographer whose id is 1 then I should get cover photo of that photographer whose id is 1.

Comment: The modeling looks odd: based on how you model the team, a `Team` has exactly *one* member, and a user can belong to multiple teams, but all these teams have one member.

Comment: I think I should create table of members and then there will be relation between team and photographer.

Comment: yes, you can work with a `ManyToManyField` such that a `Team` can have many members.